# Omnet access method of another submodule error - no matching function for call to ‘check_and_cast(cModule*&)’

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

**Error:** no matching function for call to ‘check_and_cast(cModule*&)’

I am trying to use the current position from another module "mobility" with n class type MassMobility.

```
cModule* parentmod = getParentModule();

cModule* mobilitymod = parentmod->getParentModule()->getSubmodule("mobility");
EV<<"Current module is "<<mobilitymod->getFullName() <<endl;

MassMobility* mobility = check_and_cast<MassMobility *>(mobilitymod);
mobility->getCurrentPosition();
```

I am getting compile time error :- `no matching function for call to ‘check_and_cast(cModule*&)’`. But still I am able to get the functions from the mobility object as shown in last line. Can anybody please suggest me how can I correct it.

Comment: "no matching *function* for call" ?? is that really the error message?

Comment: `no matching function for call to ‘check_and_cast(cModule*&)’ ` its the exact error. I apologize that I haven't notice last time

Comment: @Karoly ovrath - I even tried to look for it omnet google group, where I got this tread :- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/omnetpp/2CNpYn6E_14 , which implies that the varaible name (mobility) should not be same as object name (mobilitymod)..

Comment: try `dynamic_cast` instead of `check_and_cast`, something in the lines of: `mobility = dynamic_cast<Veins::TraCIMobility*>(tmpMobility);` and then add an assert: `ASSERT(mobility);`

Comment: did you have the `Enter_Method("<method_name>")` macro in the _public_ method that is called from outside? And maybe the method you are trying to call is a just a prototype without the actual implementation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figure out the problem. First thing I needed to add header file of mobility module in my current sub module to get the definitions. So I included-

```
#include "MassMobility.h"
#include "StationaryMobility.h"
```

then in code I did following modification:-

```
cModule* parentmod = getParentModule();
cModule* mobilitymod = parentmod->getParentModule()->getSubmodule("mobility");
MassMobility* massMobilityMod = dynamic_cast<MassMobility*>(mobilitymod);
EV<<"Current position is <<"massMobilityMod->getCurrentPosition();
```

So the reason for the errors is the lack of definitions, which is provided by the header files in this solution.