# Accessing MAC layer information at Application layer OMNeT++

Tags: networking, simulation, omnet++

I need to access txPower variable (which is available at the Mac1609_4 class) into the BaseWaveApplLayer.cc file.
 Please tell me how to do it.

thanks

Comment: you will need to clarify your question in order to get an answer which really helps your case. There are many ways to access a given parameter of the simulation. You can modify it from the `omnetpp.ini` file or if you want to change it dynamically in the runtime, then a more complex process is needed. But before receiving an answer you will need to clarify your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct me If I am not able to understand your question completly. 
I hope you have the mac module and waveApp or other application layer module in your simulation (or more precisely in ned file). 
Now if you want to access a variable of a module or a submodule (here Mac) in another module (here app )then you need to create the object of Mac module in app module's cpp file and then need to instantiate the object to access all the methods and variables. For details first go through  :- https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec181

You can also check this link, where I ask similar question:-[Omnet access method of another submodule error - no matching function for call to ‘check_and_cast(cModule*&)’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30225285/omnet-access-method-of-another-submodule-error-no-matching-function-for-call-t)